# Как вывести зарегистрированные таксономии?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как вывести зарегистрированные таксономии, такие как category и post_tag и назначить их произвольному типу записи ? Зарегистрированных произвольных таксономий может быть много.
На странице настроек произвольного типа записи нужно вывести список таксономий(category, post_tag), на против каждой таксономии должен быть флажок выбора нужной таксономии.
т.е. нужно сделать возможным выбрать нужную таксономию и назначить эту таксономию для произвольного типа. Такой вариант, как register_post_type не подходит, т.к. нужно назначать таксономию именно с помощью выбора из списка имеющихся таксономий на странице настроек произвольного типа.  Плагины также не подходят.
Пытался вывести метки с помощью $tags = get_tags(), но почему-то возвращается пустой массив хотя метки есть, поэтому в недоумении и прошу помощи.

Comment: Вы хотите тут, чтобы вам целый плагин расписали. И таксономии вывести, и флажки расставить (оформить страницу опций), и ряд условий соблюсти. Хорошо, хоть get_tags вынесли в отдельный вопрос, он тут вообще не в тему. Вопрос все равно слишком общий, выходит за рамки StackOverflow. Непонятно, что вы сделали сами. Поэтому с такой задачей лучше обращаться на фриланс.

Comment: мне не нужно расписывать про то, как создавать флажки. Это само собой понятно, что совсем другой вопрос, не относящийся к теме.  
Мне важно хотя-бы знать, как вывести эти таксономии и как их назначить произвольному типу.

Comment: скорее всего на первый вопрос я нашёл ответ, это с помощью get_taxonomies()

Comment: теперь мне нужно узнать, как эти таксономии правильно назначить для произвольного типа на странице настроек. Для этого скорее всего подойдёт функция register_taxonomy_for_object_type, но её нужно вызывать на хуке init, а страница настроек загружается до этого хука

Comment: итого, мне нужно было узнать всего две функции: get_taxonomies()  и register_taxonomy_for_object_type ) .

Comment: @ KAGG Design, для этого не нужно обращаться на фриланс  скорее всего, чтобы мне сказали про две функции